# VB.Net DateTimePicker how to stop navigation button from setting a default date

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, datetimepicker

I have added a DateTimePicker to my windows forms vb app. Its sets the date when left or right navigation button is clicked. I want to the box to be populated only when an date is clicked. Currently when the navigation button is clicked a date gets set in the box.I looked around in stackoverflow and google but not finding a solution to this specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the my mistake. I needed to handle the 'DateSelected' event and not the 'DateChanged' event. DateChanged events are getting fired as part for the month changes when clicked on the left/right navigator button and also when the year changes.